# Objective-C – reloading a UITableView without noticing the user

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How can I reload a `UITableView` without noticing the user behind the iDevice?

I'm updating my `UITableView`s datasource in `-applicationWillEnterForeground:` by sending a notification to my RootViewController that observes the notification and runs a selector that calls `[self.table reloadData]` but I want this update to be made in stealth and not showed to the user.

It seems that `-viewWillAppear:` is fired before `-applicationWillEnterForeground:`

Comment: What alert / information is given to the user such that they know the table has been reloaded?

Comment: When `[self.table reloadData]` is called a row (or many rows) disappears. I don't want to show this for the user.

Comment: So what is your desired outcome? The table doesn't change?

Comment: That the table is updated with new data BUT not showing the actual deletion of the row(s). Maybe I'm looking for something else than reloadData?

Comment: Look at the UITableView reference method `insertRowAtIndexPaths` and others with `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` (or try other animations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your question, but I think what you're looking for is a way to reload the data before it appears on screen, yes?

I'd say figure out a way to call your data refresh method directly, not via a notification. The notification de-couples the data refresh from `-applicationWillEnterForeground`, giving the view time to appear.

Sequence is probably something like this:

1. `applicationWillEnterForeground`
2. `viewWillAppear`
3. The view appears.
4. Notification observer method is called

   a) Notification observer method calls [self.table reloadData]
5. Table view refreshes on-screen.

What you want is to couple your notification method to a method that gets called before the view appears. Call it directly from `applicationWillEnterForeground` or `viewWillAppear`.

That way it'll play out like this:

1. `applicationWillEnterForeground`

   a) your data refresh method is called. (no need to call [self.table reloadData], the tableView hasn't loaded the data at all yet.)
2. `viewWillAppear`
3. The view appears.
4. Table view is loaded with already refreshed data.

or like this:

1. `applicationWillEnterForeground`
2. `viewWillAppear`

   a) your data refresh method is called. (no need to call [self.table reloadData], the tableView hasn't loaded the data at all yet.)
3. The view appears.
4. Table view is loaded with already refreshed data.

Comment: Actually I'm doing it precisely like the second method that you are suggesting but for some reason -viewWillAppear is running before -applicationWillEnterForeground

Comment: So move your data-reload code into -viewWillAppear? What's the real problem here? I was working on the assumption that it was "data not loaded before view appears, so there is a visible refresh"

Comment: How are you loading your data, anyway? is it a network operation...?

Comment: The problem is that I don't want the data to be downloaded every time the view will appear. I just want the data to be updated once the app has been in the background and brought to foreground.

Comment: If you have a network operation, the right thing to do is show the UI, then throw up a spinner, or something else to indicate a refresh... then when the data is loaded, run `reloadData`. There is a moment where your old data is shown, but that's because network operations take time. Alternatively, have `applicationWillEnterforeground` not load your RootViewController until it's received data from the network.

Comment: Aha, it was my understanding that `-applicationWillEnterForeground` is loaded BEFORE my RootViewController is loaded. How do I achieve NOT loading my RootViewController in `-applicationWillEnterForeground` ?

Comment: @PeterWarbo it is loaded before, but network operations take time and happen in the background, so your RootViewController is appearing before the load is done. `-applicationWillEnterForeground` can call `[rootViewController.view removeFromSuperview];` to hide the view, and then when the download is done you can call `[window addSubview:rootViewController.view];`